# MongoDB dabase fetching gives an empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

I am new in MERN Stack and stuck in fething data from mongoDB Database. database connection is established successfully, Schema and model are developed and the hard coded data in database is exactly same as schema. Code is below,

I am trying to fetch data but it returns an empty array [].

[image: MongoDB database image]

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const quoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: "string",
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: "string",
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  heading: {
    type: "string",
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  content: {
    type: "string",
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
  },
});

const Quote = mongoose.model("Quote", quoteSchema);

module.exports = Quote;
```

MongoDB document;

_id: 63fa9afdb9a2ce7ac01
name: "name"
email: "email@gmail.com"
heading: "heading"
content: "Here goes content

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Quote = require("./modals/quoteModal");
const app = express();
```

```
mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Database connection successful");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(`Database is not connected ${error}`);
  });

app.get("/quotes", (req, res) => {
  Quote.find({}, (err, quotes) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      console.log(quotes);
      res.status(200).json({
        quotes,
      });
    }
  });
});

const host = "localhost";
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`MERN-App is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
  console.log(Quote.schema.obj);
});
```

Comment: please show the mongo connection as well, you may connected to server but not selected the database.

Comment: You are missing the `app.use(express.json())` middleware

Comment: @TobokSitanggang, I update the question Please check it and this is all I wrote in my files

Comment: @lpizzinidev I added it but it still does not work, please check the updated question, I added a photo how my database looks like